# PuTTY shortcut using target: How to specify port?

Tags: ssh, putty

I'd like to create a shortcut for connecting to my web server + logging in on Putty. The following has always worked for me but I recently have gotten a new web host that connects with a port other than the default 22, thus my normal target line doesn't work anymore:

```
"C:\Program Files\PuTTY\putty.exe" <user>@<host> -pw <password>
```

How do I to specify the port?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/0.70/htmldoc/Chapter3.html#S3.8.3.7):

```
... -P otherport ...
```

Answer (score -3):

```
@echo off 
C: 
cd \Program Files\PuTTY
start putty.exe -ssh user@IP 22(port) -pw 1234566789(psswrd)
exit
```

Put this in a text file and then all you have to do is change the extension to `.bat` and then double click it to open a session with your user.

Comment: This answer is wrong. You have to use the `-P` parameter to specify the port.